# Display Infolog when selecting record in dropdown menu

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Is there a way to display an info log when selecting a certain record in a dropdown menu/based on a field value?

For example:

When creating a new Quotation, if I select a customer which is bankrupt (so the value on the field bankrupt is `true` for that customer.) I want to show a info dialog: "Bankrupt!" I want to show this before the record is being created, at the moment it is being selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your form find the field you want (form layout, no datasource), override `Modified` method an put your code before `super();`

To get the value use: `this.text();` Here you can get the select value before insert.

***Code example:***

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean   ret;
    CustTable custTable = CustTable::find(this.text());    
    if (custTable.Bankrupt == NoYes::Yes)
        info("Bankrupt!"); 

    ret = super();

    return ret;
}
```